# How to authorize against an OAUth 2.0 API (fatsecret) with flutter

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I want to authorize myself against the fatsecret service and get a token. I tried to follow the documentation at https://platform.fatsecret.com/api/Default.aspx?screen=rapiauth2 and rewrite the given curl code in flutter, but I can't get it to work.

I have already tried different types of requests (post, get), I tried to put the authorization into the url and I tried different encodings. Nothing changed unfortunately. This is the last I've tried:

```
static void _authorizeClient() async {

  Map<String, String> params = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'scope': 'basic',
  };

  Map<String, String> headers = {
    HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
        'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode(clientId + ':' + clientSecret))
  };

  http.Response response = await http.post(
      Uri.https('oauth.fatsecret.com', 'connect/token', params),
      headers: headers);

  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
}
```

When I run the curl code on their website I get a token without a problem, but my code just doesn't work, I always get a 400 - bad request.

Comment: Yeah OAuth sucks, I wish they'd just use a simple token based API like everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Oauth is not a simple post request, so that code is not gonna work.
You don't want to implement an oauth library from scratch since you would be in for a looong headache with encryption, unsuccesful post requests , and not knowing the oauth flow . I would suggest using a oAuth2 library like [this one](https://github.com/dart-lang/oauth2) . If you really want to create your own library, i can point you to the [oauth2 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

Maybe you will say "But when I run the curl code on their website I get a token without a problem", to that i would respond. Maybe the website already has you credentials, or some cookies , or secret, and it's sending it without you knowing. Try using PostMan [or RestMan if you use Opera] to test clean GET and POST requests without any extra data.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that,